# Error in 'date -d' command

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, date, coreutils

Hmmm... Right now (Sat Oct 24 00:36:56 CDT 2015) on my Arch Linux system there appears to be a problem with the date command:

```
$ date -d "+8 days" "+%A %d %B %Y"
Sunday 01 November 2015

$ date -d "+9 days" "+%A %d %B %Y"
Sunday 01 November 2015
```

I am using this in a script to display my schedule on my desktop that this error causes to print Sunday twice on.  I know I could fashion a workaround, but a core utility like this should be working correctly, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Daylight Savings Time ends on Nov 1.

After 2:00 am, you should see November 2 as the output of the second command.  November 1 has a couple of extra hours.

Comment: Yup, this is indeed what was happening.